# Looking for Linux software for wifi survey/traffic analysis

Tags: wifi

I want to evaluate the amount of traffic for a wifi AP over a certain period of time (say a day or so). I don't need to capture any packets or try to inspect the packages. It is really just checking the traffic being sent and received to an AP over a longer period. Which Linux-based tools can you recommend for this task. It is not the amount of packages but the amount of bytes I am interested in.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to investigate alternate firmware for your router.  Like DD-wrt or open-wrt or etc.

Then you can use standard tools like iptables,ipset, ulogd,or etc.

**iptables -A INPUT**

Then later

```
iptables -xvn -L
```

[image]

Where column 1 is packets and column 2 is bytes.

ipset can configured with the counter option which will also count packets and bytes.

ulogd can be access through iptables entries to send the output to a number of destinations not limited to but including database.

```
iptables **conditions** -j NFLOG
```

Obviously /etc/ulogd.conf need to be setup in advance.